# Node.js asynchronous requests with APDU

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

Thanks to ponury-kostek I solved half of my problem. The initial sequential functions already work. Now I only have troubles with a cycle.

Here I need to read 6 chunks of sequential data by order. I need to do 6 requests changing one parameter, the offset (that increases by one each time).

Let's say I got the data in the format of ABCDEF, each one being a chunk of 258 bytes. I want to read it in that order and store it in a variable or a file.

Since the functions are async I'm getting AEFDBC or ABFDEC or ...

```
console.log("---get bin "+offset+"---")
```

Can I also make it work with promises?

The code:

```
function getBinPromise(){
    var foffset = 0x00;
    var i = 0;
    for(i=0; i<6;){
        getBinChunkPromise(foffset).then(i++)
        foffset = foffset + 0x01;
    } 
}


function getBinChunkPromise(offset){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        GetBinApdu = new
        Buffer( [0x00, 0xB0, offset, 0x00, 0x00] );
        reader.transmit(GetBinApdu, 258, protocol, function (err, data) {
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
                reject(err);
            } else {
                console.log("---get bin "+offset+"---")
                console.log('Data received:', data);
                console.log('Last two:', data[data.length-2], data[data.length-1]);
                fs.appendFileSync("data.txt", data);
                console.log("------");
                resolve(data);
            }
        })
    })
}
```

Sorry if this is idiot, I'm new with JS

Comment: Can you add sequence numbers to the APDU?

Comment: @ThingyWotsit I don't think so. I'm using this the transmit function of this module https://github.com/santigimeno/node-pcsclite

Comment: You have a question about your code, then you have to show us your code. **"(I think it's because it calls the transmit function, which has a callback where I'm doing the data storing."** So *show* us then and we'll tell you where the problem is. It sounds like it absolutely can be solved using promises but we are not mind readers you know; We can't guess what code you have.

Comment: @ippi sorry about that, I'll edit my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `resolve`/`reject` inside `transmit` callback function. So you will get something like this:

```
function selectAppPromise(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        SelectAppletApdu = new Buffer( [0x00,  0xA4,  0x04, 0x00, 0x07, 0x60, 0x46, 0x32, 0xff, 0x00, appletoffset, 0x02] );
        console.log("---select app---");
        reader.transmit(SelectAppletApdu, 40, protocol, function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                reject(err);
            } else {
                console.log('Data received:', data);
                console.log('Last two:',data[data.length-2],data[data.length-1]);
                resolve(data);
            }
        });
    })
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
function getBinPromise() {
    var foffset = 0x00;
    var promises = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        promises.push(getBinChunkPromise);
    }
    promises.reduce((prevTask, current) => {
        return prevTask.then(current);
    }, Promise.resolve(foffset)).then(() => {
        console.log('all done');
    });
}
function getBinChunkPromise(offset) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        GetBinApdu = new Buffer([
            0x00,
            0xB0,
            offset,
            0x00,
            0x00
        ]);
        reader.transmit(GetBinApdu, 258, protocol, function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                reject(err);
            } else {
                console.log("---get bin " + offset + "---");
                console.log('Data received:', data);
                console.log('Last two:', data[data.length - 2], data[data.length - 1]);
                fs.appendFileSync("data.txt", data);
                console.log("------");
                resolve(offset + 0x01);
            }
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: This does work for my initial functions, but how should I do it in a cycle? Check my edit in the post. Sorry for bothering you, you already helped me a lot

Comment: @jm8FE try this.

Comment: works fine, exactly what I needed. I don't think I would've got it. Thanks for everything! You're awesome

Comment: No problem I'm happy I could help :)